# How was the first magnet made?

Tags: magnetic-fields, universe

An iron ore (natural magnet) in the earth's crust gets magnetized due to another magnet near it which aligns all its domains in one direction. We mine up that ore and use it to make other magnets (artificial magnets). The original magnet that had magnetized the ore had itself got magnetized due to another magnet. This forms a chain. But, how would have the first magnet been made??

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a magnet to create another one. That's an incorrect assumption.

Magnets are created by running an electrical current through a material, so there is no need to have a 'first magnet'.
This is happening 'naturally' in the earth core, in the sun, and in other stars.

Check the Maxwell equations, which in a nutshell say that *every moving charge creates a magnetic field*.

Comment: More specifically, natural magnets found on earth are believed to be magnetized by [lightning strikes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lodestone#:~:text=4%20External%20links-,Origin,is%20found%20magnetized%20as%20lodestone.&text=The%20leading%20theory%20is%20that,magnetic%20fields%20surrounding%20lightning%20bolts.).

Answer (score 1):

Protons, neutrons and electrons are permanent magnets. As far as we know these always existed. When heavier elements were and are aggregated in exploding stars, some of these have permanent magnetic moments as well. During planetary formation these atoms aggregated to make ferromagnetic ores that on planets like Earth were magnetised by the planetary magnetic field.

Comment: Hey thanks...  One more question: Magnetic domains in ferromagnetic substances are macroscopic (about 1mm). So, can we just scrap domains with same directions of magnetic moment from different iron ores and stick them together? We can form a magnet this way.